# v(t) is 0 and a(t) is positive

Tags: calculus

I was taking my test last period and my friend made a good point about my answer. The question was when is the particle speeding up with the given function, $v(t)=t^2-4t+3$ on time interval $0<t<9$ (pretend those are greater/less than or equal), and I can’t tell if the particle starts speeding up at $t=3$ because at that time $a(t)=2$ and $v(t)=0$ would the particle still be slowing down since it is approaching zero from the negative axis making it speed up on interval [4,9] (my answer) or would it be [3,9] (my friends answer)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $a = dv/dt = 2t-4$, which is negative until $t=2s$. After $t=2s$, it is positive.

Comment: yes thus is true but velocity is negative at 2 sec meaning the particle would be slowing down since their opposite

Comment: Negative velocity does not means slowing down, it means the particle is moving in the opposite direction from your positive direction. So the question relies on the definition of "speeding up". Does that mean when is the acceleration positive or when is the acceleration positive and velocity greater or equal to 0?

Comment: @Chase "Speed up" and "Slow down" can be confusing terms when the velocity is allowed to become negative. Distinguish carefully what you mean by it and the confusion goes away.

Comment: @Andrei correct, but when the velocity was negative in this particular equation and the acceleration is positive. since they are opposite signs that indicates the particle is slowing down. however this is not too relevant to the question at hand because I do not know if the particle is speeding up when the velocity is 0(approaching from the negative axis) and acceleration is 2. could this be fixed using parenthesis instead of brackets

Comment: @KurtG. it does get confusing, what about when the particle has a 0 velocity and a positive acceleration. Would I include this time when talking about the intervals the particle is speeding up.

Answer (score 1):

This is an English problem, not a mathematics one.  The speed, which is the absolute value of the velocity, is increasing when the acceleration and velocity are in the same direction and decreasing when they are in the same direction.  We start out with $v$ negative and $a$ negative, so the speed is increasing.  At $t=2$ the acceleration changes sign and the magnitude of the velocity starts decreasing.  At $t=3$ the velocity changes sign, both quantities are positive, and the speed starts increasing.  The answer would be different if you were asked when the velocity is increasing/decreasing.

Comment: Thank you lots I did not know if velocity being zero should be considered speeding up since it was approaching from the negative side with a positive acceleration